# GASエラー「ドキュメント（～略～）がありません。ドキュメントが削除されたか、読み取りアクセス権がない可能性があります。」

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

#### 現象

GASによって自動で定期的にスプレッドシートを読み書きするスクリプトに表題のエラーが時々出ます。
何回も同じスクリプトをトリガーで起動しており、99％は問題なく処理を終えるのですが、1%以下の確率で同様のエラーが出現します。

#### エラー内容

・ドキュメント（～略～）がありません。ドキュメントが削除されたか、読み取りアクセス権がない可能性があります。
・ストレージからの読み取り中にサーバーエラーが発生しました。エラーコード: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED。

#### お願いしたいこと

エラーの発生をなくす方法をご教示お願いします。
無くすことが無理なら、運用でカバーする工夫をご教示お願いします。

#### スクリプト内容

下記のスクリプトを１分ごとに起動するトリガーを設定しております。コンテナバインドです。

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('シート1');
const data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues(); //受け取ったシートのデータを二次元配列に取得

function myFunction() {
    let lastRow = data.length
    sheet.getRange(lastRow+1,1).setValue('値を入力１');
    sheet.getRange(lastRow+1,2).setValue('値を入力２');
    sheet.getRange(lastRow+1,3).setValue('値を入力３');
}
```

Comment: 私の能力不足でスクリプトをちゃんと読めませんが、スクリプトの問題ではない可能性もあると思います。スクリプトに問題がない場合、原因を考えるための情報が不足していると思います。試しに２分毎に実行してみて、発生頻度が減るかを確認してはいかがでしょうか？また、処理開始時刻と終了時刻を記録して確認するのもひとつの方法です。処理時間はどのくらいか？発生時刻に偏りがないか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。過去に行った検証としては４日間１分毎のトリガー実行。処理時間としては1~3秒、エラーが出ているときは長くて6秒。発生時間も１４時，９時，８時，４時，２時，０時と偏りは見られませんでした。エラー率0.11％でした。AppsScriptは７日以上のログは破棄されるようなので、もう一度７日間検証を行ってみます。

Comment: 1週間、１分毎に回し続けましたが、エラー率0.11%で発生率もやはり23時、19時、１０時、21時、11時と規則性は見つかりませんでした。弊社のシステムに聞いてもセキュリティで弾くようなことはないはず、とのことでした。起因がわからない状態です。GASの運用方法を改善させ、スプレッドシートに読み書きするようなスクリプトにはフラギングをして、エラーが起きても次の1分後のトリガー起動で処理されるようにしております。